# How to solve assertion error status 404 in web mvc test

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, mockito

I have a controller like this ,This seems to be a problem with Spring boot
No one has been able to solve this issue , The same issue was raised by another user , check link [Error when using @WebMvcTest annotation on a Spring Boot test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231731/error-when-using-webmvctest-annotation-on-a-spring-boot-test-class/43192369)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBookPost(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        bookService.save(book);
        MultipartFile bookImage = book.getBookImage();
        try  {//do something
        }
        return "redirect:bookList";
    }
```

This is the test I have generated using @WebMvcTest

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {BookController.class}, includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(classes = EnableWebSecurity.class))
public class BookControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;


    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "admin", authorities = {"ADMIN"})
    public void addBookClicked() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/book/add")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)).andExpect(status().isOk())

                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("book"))
                .andExpect(view().name("addBook"))
                .andReturn();
    }
```

This is a configuration that imports beans from app.properties

```
 @Configuration
    @Import({PropertyTestConfiguration.class, SecurityUtility.class})
    static class ContextConfiguration {
    }
```

I get this error

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /book/add
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {}

java.lang.AssertionError: Range for response status value 404 
Expected :REDIRECTION
Actual   :CLIENT_ERROR
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.valentine.adminportal.controller.BookControllerTest.TestWithoutAuthentication(BookControllerTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
```

Note that this test passes when use @SpringBootTest the test passes ,Any help would suffice. Thank you , I have used references from springio and other sites and my test is basically the same so I don't know where my error is coming from.

Comment: provide actual [mcve] as the error shown is for `/book/remove` while the code is for `/book/add`

Comment: yes I don't get why it shows that @Nkosi as you can see I gave it uri book/add

Comment: i will reduce my code thank you

Comment: also notice that in the test you perform a `GET` while the request mapping is configured for `POST`

Comment: yes you are right ,i just updated it and it still gives the same error @Nkosi

Comment: I have five web Tests and all have the same problem ,if i use SpringBootTest it works but WebMvcTest for some reason has a problem @Nkosi

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or not but this link shows another user with the same problem   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231731/error-when-using-webmvctest-annotation-on-a-spring-boot-test-class/43192369

Comment: Well if the `@SpringBootTest` annotation works, it means that your set of libraries (spring) have some incompatibility with the `@WebMvcTest` In order to find out the problem even the solution you would need to use the  `@SpringBootTest` and debug into the spring libraries and then do the same using the `@WebMvcTest` annotation and see what is the difference. It will take quite some time of course, but you will find it out. The option to that is thoroughly read the documentation for both annotations and find what you are missing.

Comment: Since no one gave a good and decisive answer that question from two years ago. And don't forget to add an answer yourself you go to through this process!

Comment: @JorgeCampos Do you mean i should annotate the  test class with springbootTest then debug a test , and do the same after using webMvcTest , or what do u mean debug the spring libraries

Comment: Debug the spring libraries trying to understand why one work and the another doesn't.

Comment: I don't see a book in the  POST body of your test code